# Why would a site not load on my desktop or laptop, but loads on my phone on the same network?

Tags: networking, laptop, website, desktop-computer, smartphone

On both Windows 10 and Arch Linux on my desktop computer, or Windows/OS X on my Macbook, Webtoons.com will not load, no matter what web browser I use. On my Android phone, the site works fine, even if I tell it to send the desktop site and I turn off mobile data. What could be happening here?

Here's a trace from my desktop on Windows:

```
>tracert webtoons.com

Tracing route to webtoons.com [125.209.214.12]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.0.1
  3    10 ms     9 ms    15 ms  10.60.64.1
  4    11 ms    10 ms   124 ms  ten8-2.detr01-ser2.bhn.net [72.31.204.248]
  5   170 ms    23 ms    10 ms  ten0-3-0-3.detr01-car1.bhn.net [72.31.205.68]
  6    11 ms    10 ms    11 ms  72-31-205-13.net.bhntampa.com [72.31.205.13]
  7    25 ms    22 ms    23 ms  24.27.236.0
  8   101 ms    70 ms    70 ms  66.109.3.243
  9    65 ms    65 ms    64 ms  0.ae0.pr0.sjc20.tbone.rr.com [66.109.6.139]
 10    97 ms    71 ms    70 ms  107.14.16.114
 11    67 ms   213 ms    65 ms  pajbb001.int-gw.kddi.ne.jp [111.87.3.5]
 12   203 ms   168 ms   268 ms  otejbb205.int-gw.kddi.ne.jp [203.181.100.173]
 13   200 ms   168 ms   313 ms  kotjbb201.kddnet.ad.jp [59.128.4.22]
 14   257 ms   355 ms   182 ms  cm-kot208.kddnet.ad.jp [125.29.22.98]
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Also, pinging the site from the desktop fails (100% packet loss), and I've tried to use a traceroute tool that's included with mobiperf on Android, but that fails for an unknown reason and doesn't give information, though the included ping tool does succeed.

Comment: I get a similar tracert, but I can visit that site.Strange issue you have. Maybe hard code it in the hosts file in Windows?

Comment: How would I do that? I've only ever used the hosts file to block things.

Comment: 125.209.214.12       webtoons.com

Comment: Host can do both, block or hard code the ip address associated with a url....  http://www.jakeludington.com/windows_7/20100827_how_do_i_edit_hosts_file_in_windows_7.html

Comment: Ahh, okay. Well, I don't think this is going to work, seeing as I also can't reach that IP with ping... I'll give it a try. EDIT: No dice, same issue.

Comment: Have you restarted the router/modem?

Comment: Yup. I just gave up and installed the app for Webtoons on my phone, and will just have to read the comics there.